# Enable/ disable „Display author and date information“ per node?

Tags: 8, nodes

It is passible to enable or disable the „Display author and date information“ for each node depending on the content of a field?

The base:

- Drupal 8.3.0 (rc2)
- field „Where to publish“

---

- Case 1: field „Where to publish“ = „public“
- Case 2: field „Where to publish“ = „internally“

-> in Case 1: disable „Display author and date information“

-> in Case 2: enable „Display author and date information“

How can this be realized? Is that possible?
Or should I use two different content types?

---

First part runs:

```
function kanu_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
if ($variables['node']->getType() != 'test') {
    return;
  }
$field = $variables['node']->field_where_to_publish;
}
```

Completed it returns an unexpected error:

```
function kanu_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->getType() != 'test') {
      return;
  }
  $field = $variables['node']->field_where_to_publish;

  if (!field->isEmpty() && $field->entity->label() == 'public') {
     $variables['display_submitted'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the variable `display_submitted` in a preprocess hook:

**mytheme.theme:**

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  // check if this is the right content type where the field exists
  if ($variables['node']->getType() != 'article') {
    return;
  }

  // plain field
  if ($variables['node']->field_where_to_publish->value == 'public') {
    $variables['display_submitted'] = FALSE;
  }

  // taxonomy field
  $field = $variables['node']->field_where_to_publish;
  if (!$field->isEmpty() && $field->entity->label() == 'public') {
    $variables['display_submitted'] = FALSE;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank You very much. This looks so simple, but already exceeds my knowledge. Can you please tell me where I have to place this snippet: in my subtheme certainly? In which file?
Regards
Frank

Comment: Put the hook in the file mytheme.theme in the root directory of your theme. Replace `mytheme` both in the file name and the hook name with the name of your theme and clear the cache.

Comment: please see above. It doesn't work, but I don't know, why.

Comment: looks good, only a `>` before the last `{` doesn't seem to belong there. Do you get any errors? Do you have a `<?php` at the beginning of the php file?

Comment: ">" - My error when transferring.
Is this a problem of the "===" ?

Comment: When I use === ‘public or == 'public', nothing happens.
When I use = 'public', then both: 'public' and 'intern' nodes have disabled author. 
It seems, that the string is not evaluated correctly. I have used a taxonomy field to use a selection list.

Comment: taxonomy is different, see edit

Comment: it seems to work without that: !field->isEmpty() && .
Is this way also a possibility to open or close comments?

Comment: It works without the check for an empty field as long as you have always selected a term, otherwise you get an error.

Comment: With this i've got an error...

Comment: I've missed a `$`, see edit

Comment: Thank you, sounds logical. I have not seen this as a non-programmer - until now. I want to try that. Thanks again,

Comment: works. Great. I invite you to a beer, if You like it.

Comment: If there are more than one Content type? article, test1 , test2? How do you program it?